# App is not listing in Google play but when click on "Get it from play store" from web it is showing in play store?

Tags: android

I have an issue when is search my app in google play store by typing name it is not listed in play store but when I click from web named as "Get it on play store" it is opening. I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It takes a while for Google Play to update the store listings. You'll have to wait a while before it becomes visible*.

It usually takes 3-6 hours after the release, though it can take longer or shorter time too.

<sub>* assuming it ranks high enough in the keyword for it to be visible.</sub>